# Curl wordpress, не работает код

Tags: wordpress, curl

Почему не работает этот код?

```
$login = c("edit1")->text;
$pass = c("edit2")->text;

$url = 'http://vxas.ru/wp-login.php';
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405';
$cookieFile = 'cookie.txt';
$data = array(
action => 'login',
imembername => $login,
ipassword => $pass,
submit => '????'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
pre ($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

На той форме, что указана в $url, имеются поля

```
log
pwd
wp-submit
redirect_to
testcookie
submit
```

вы же передаете

```
action
imembername
ipassword
```

при чем у вас в строчке формирования $data PHP должен падать с ошибкой парсинга скрипта, т.к. эти параметры должны быть заключены в кавычки